# Looking for a conlang I once encountered

Tags: resource-request

I am looking for a conlang I once encountered. Sadly I lack specific and reliable info, but I'll dump what I can recollect.

It was built from simple semantic units (syllables?), with the latter developing and specifying the meaning of the previous. Perhaps there was even more structure, in the grammar or how the syllables were initially arranged. In this regard it seems quite similar to Ygyde.

I think it had a concise and pretty name, possibly starting with D. When searching I came across Damin, but that is obviously not the one.

It was no toy project. It seemed like the author had put a lot of effort to it and the work was still progressing. He claimed the language was to be ideal in some sense, as if he was reconstructing a primordial universal language or if the current languages were to converge to this one. But I don't think it had any speakers, or any significant number of them.

I failed to find it through search engines and through public conlang lists. I looked into engineered languages at Wikipedia and I can tell I am not looking for Toki Pona, Loglan, Lojban or Ithkuil

Comment: Was it perhaps [Dunia](http://web.archive.org/web/20120601005039/http://www.langmaker.com/outpost/dunia.htm)?

Comment: thanks, that looks quite close. unfortunately it is not the lang, and surely not the source i read before. the original was more extensive (it felt quite overwhelming). i think the author was not anonymous and that there was even a bit of his biography. and his attitude was less pragmatic and more mystical

Comment: as a follow up, [Mirad](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Mirad_Grammar) is also very similar. and more importantly, i've acquired an insight that there are loads of conlangs out there and that whatever my mystery lang was, it was not unique in any of its attributes

Answer (score 3):

I just came across an old bookmark leading to [Dama Diwan](https://linguifex.com/wiki/Dama_Diwan) and it is my mystery language! complete with the claims of minimality, optimality, construction through divination, ...

... case closed